# PrimeReact. ContextMenu labels color. Is there any way to change the font color of the labels in ContextMenu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, primereact

I am using the PrimeReact ContextMenu component to show multiple options in my UI.
Now is there any way we can set different label color for each menu items?
Example:

```js
const items = [
{
  label: "label1",
  template: (item, options) => (
    <div
      className={options.className}
      onClick={options.onClick}
    >
      <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
        {item.label}
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}]
```

Works correctly in version 7.0.0, but not in 9.5.0.

Comment: You just need  to find and  override the value in that class.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to pass a reactNode to the 'label' property of the 'Item'

```
const items = [
{ label: "View", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-search" },
{
  label: <span style={{ color: "red" }}> Delete </span>,
  icon: "pi pi-fw pi-trash"
} ];
```